# Camunda does not contain any history

Tags: camunda

I have a problem that whenever I create a process instance in Camunda Process Service, it does not write anything to ACT_HI_OP_LOG. I am not sure why it is not saving the histories into database.

```
@Component
@Order(Ordering.DEFAULT_ORDER + 1)
public class ProcessEngineConfiguration implements ProcessEnginePlugin {

    private String tenantId;

    @Override
    public void preInit(ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl processEngineConfiguration) {
        HistoryLevel historyLevel = new HistoryLevelFull();
        processEngineConfiguration.setHistoryLevel(historyLevel);
        processEngineConfiguration.setTenantCheckEnabled(true);
//      processEngineConfiguration.setHistory(org.camunda.bpm.engine.ProcessEngineConfiguration.HISTORY_FULL);
        processEngineConfiguration.setTenantIdProvider(new TenantIdProvider() {

            @Override
            public String provideTenantIdForProcessInstance(TenantIdProviderProcessInstanceContext ctx) {
                return tenantId;
            }

            @Override
            public String provideTenantIdForHistoricDecisionInstance(TenantIdProviderHistoricDecisionInstanceContext ctx) {
                return tenantId;
            }

            @Override
            public String provideTenantIdForCaseInstance(TenantIdProviderCaseInstanceContext ctx) {
                return tenantId;
            }
        });

        processEngineConfiguration.setJobExecutor(processEngineConfiguration.getJobExecutor());

    }
```

This is how I start the process.

```
ProcessInstance pi = null;

        try {
            identityService.setAuthentication(getAuthentication());
            pi = runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey(flowName, businessKey, variables);


        } finally {
            identityService.setAuthentication(null);
        }
        if (pi == null)
            return null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check configuration?

`historyLevelCheckEnabled` default value is `true`.

Can you try to set that value `false`.

If you set that false, this check would not be performed.